# Coldfusion 9 cfexchangecalendar exchange server outlook 2007

Tags: coldfusion, exchange-server, coldfusion-9

CF9
Exchange server 2007 (hosted)

I am trying to add a calendar event for a user on our hosted exchange server. I'm getting the error ;
Unable to connect to the Exchange server using HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

HTTP response code : 400

The code is;

```
<cfexchangeCalendar action="Create" 
    username="EXCH016\ron_domain"
    password="password" 
    mailboxname="ron"
    server="https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/owa"
    Protocol="https"
    formbasedauthentication=true
    formbasedauthenticationURL="https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/owa/auth/owaauth.dll"
    Event="#sEvent#"
    result="theUID">

    #theUID#<br>
```

I know I can contact the server using the following;

```
<cfhttp URL='https://owa016.msoutlookonline.net/owa' result='res' >
<cfdump var="#res#">
<cfoutput>#res.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

I get the form that requests email address and password.

I've been working on this problem for some time now.  I can go to the owa page via browser and log in.  At this point I'm at a loss on how to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same type of problem in the past, when one of my customers went from Privately Hosted and Run vs Hosted Solutions.

Although, I never used the formbasedauthentication method when authenticating, maybe this bypasses some of my issues.

The big thing we had issues with is that most Providers don't all WebDav access on their servers. 
Since you are getting a 400, bad request, this is what I would look for first.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=cfexchange_3.html talks about what CF needs to connect to Exchange, maybe see if the support staff can confirm the setup.

Since you are using HTTPS, have you added the Cert into the JRE cert Store?

Sorry this probably isn't much help, but I hope it helps.